# Multiple Conditions in C for same integer

Tags: c

I am trying to prompt the user, for a positive integer which must not exceed `23`, and if this is not fulfilled the user should get reprompted. This is my code so far:

```
int main(void) { 
    int n = 0;    
    do     
    {         
        printf("please give me a positive integer not greater than 23:");     
        n = GetInt();     
    }  
    while (n<0);

    printf ("Thanks for the Valid Number!");  
    return 0; 
}
```

('GetInt()'is a library function that I am using).

This works, however for the while condition, when I add `&& n>23`, to fulfil my second condition,  my code fails and `thanks me` for both negative numbers and numbers above 23. Is it something that I am missing.

*Note: I'm completely new to C so I am trying to leaner it myself, and it would be great if someone can help me.*

Comment: Not `&&`  but `||`. You need to take the loop while **either** condition holds.

Comment: "&&" is the logical "and", which means *both* conditions have to be true. What you want is "||", which is the logical "or" which means *at least* one of these two is true (as opposed to logical "exclusive or"/xor which means *exactly* one of these two things is true)

Comment: As has been said, you want *either* condition to be true to continue the loop, not *both* (which is impossible).  So use the logical OR operator, i.e. `||`, to combine the two conditions:  `while (n < 0 || n > 23)`

Comment: Why the downvotes though? OP doesn't understand logical operators, the question itself isn't that bad though.

Answer (score 3):

```
int n;

do {
    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);
} while(n<0 || n>23);
```

This is basically the code.

What you want is the use to enter a number.
If the number is Less than 0 or greater than 23 the condition would restart an input hence a while loop.

Comment: You should also check the return value of `scanf()` before relying on `n` to have a valid value.

Comment: He doesn't need `scanf` at all actually, since he already uses `GetInt`.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use &&, you'd have to do `while (!(n >= 0 && n <= 23))` or `while (!(!(n < 0) && !(n > 23))`. These are both equivalent to `while (n < 0 || n > 23)`. Check this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws (the second is more a direct application of DeMorgan's Law, but the first is easier to understand as well as read).

Comment: Your nswer is correct but I think you are just confusing OP.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you print n when it is returned by GetInt() with something like:

```
printf("value: %d", n);
```

With this value you can see debug you code and see if it does what you want.

If I understand you correctly you just want a integer that is 23 or lower. This means that the do-while loop had te be executed for every n higher than 23. The code will be something like this:

```
int n = 0;

do {
   n = GetInt();
}
while (n > 23);
```

So at first you enter the do part of the loop which calls `GetInt()` and returns the value into `n`. After the do scope (everything between these brackets {}) is executed you enter the statement of the do-while loop, `while (n > 23);`. Which means, "while  `n` exceeds 23 then execute `do {}`". This keeps repeating itself till `n` is 23 or smaller.

I hope you understand it now. If you want to get started with C/C++ buy a book, it really helped me alot. More informations about loops and operators for the statement can be found at the following links:

loops: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_loops.htm
operators: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_operators.htm